# ¿Por qué se pueden tener etiquetas anidadas y por qué se permite y el resultado no es considerado erróneo?

Tags: html, html5

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 
</head>

<body>

<strong><em>Texto emfatizado</em></strong>

</body>
</html>
```

Tengo entendido que `<strong>` es para marcar texto de gran importancia y que los scream readers le "narran ese texto" a los usuarios de una forma diferente para que resalte más. Pero su contenido ¿no debe de ser meramente texto? pero en este caso su contenido es una etiqueta y no un texto para poder marcarlo como importante.

¿O es que el elemento `<em>` se vuelve uno solo con el texto que contiene y técnicamente `<em>` junto con su contenido son considerado una sola cosa (un texto como tal solo que con énfasis) y por eso es válido que `<strong>` lo tenga como padre?

¿De la misma forma podría interpretar otras etiquetas que estén anidadas?

Comment: ¿Podrías delimitar correctamente las interrogaciones en el párrafo final de tu pregunta? No entiendo el sentido de ese párrafo y no llego a entender exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No se entiende nada de nada?..

Comment: Ahora queda un poco más claro lo que preguntas. Te busco la documentación oficial del W3C.

Comment: [El comportamiento del contenido de texto (contenido de frases)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) está resumido como **most elements that are categorized as phrasing content can only contain elements that are themselves categorized as phrasing content, not any flow content** o, que la mayoría de elementos están categorizados como contenido de texto y sólo pueden contener otros elementos de contenido de texto.

Comment: Es decir, elementos `<em>` pueden contener elementos `<strong>` y viceversa, pero no pueden contener elementos de flujo como un encabezado `<h1>`, párrafo `<p>`, sección `<section>`, tabla `<table>`, etc. Es la única limitación que impone el estándar. El uso es libre por parte de los usuarios e incluso los navegadores deberían permitir romper esa norma (con resultados que podrían variar de un navegador a otro).